# How do I see my Amazon view history?

Tags: amazon

I recall a book that I've viewed on Amazon (went to the project page) that I think I dismissed too quickly. I can't recall the name of the book, but is there a way to view the history of the products I've viewed on Amazon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Click on "Your Account" in the upper right of the main page.
2. At the bottom, click "View and edit your browsing history"

Answer (score 3):

This isn't visible in my Account menu.  There is a Tab in the .com version called *My browsing history*, but not in the .co.uk implementation of the site.
In neither case could I find what I know I have browsed for.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/history

Answer (score 2):

Ah! I was wondering the same thing and finally found it:

Go into "Your Account" --> bottom box called "Personalization" there is a section called "Personalized Content" and in there you'll find "View and Manange your browsing history"